# Only load modal content when clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

Right now when I load the page, the iframe content is loaded making the page load for quite awhile. I only need the iframe within the modal to load if the button to open the modal is clicked. Below is my code now.

Jquery:

```
$('#ticketViewBtn<?php echo $num; ?>').ready(function(){
    var url = $("#ticketModalSrc<?php echo $num; ?>").attr('src');

    $("#ticketView<?php echo $num; ?>").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#ticketModalSrc<?php echo $num; ?>").attr('src', '');
    });

    $("#ticketView<?php echo $num; ?>").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
        $("#ticketModalSrc<?php echo $num; ?>").attr('src', url);
    });
});
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-<?php echo $buttonColor; ?> btn-sm" id="#ticketViewBtn<?php echo $num; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ticketView<?php echo $num; ?>">
    <?php echo $title; ?>
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ticketView<?php echo $num; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ticketViewLabel<?php echo $num; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ticketViewLabel<?php echo $num; ?>"><?php echo "Viewing ". $ticketNum; ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe id="ticketModalSrc" width="800" height="700" src="https://txgc.texas811.org/geocall/portal?ticket=<?php echo $ticketNum; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <span class="form-control-static pull-left"><em><a target="_blank" href="https://txgc.texas811.org/geocall/portal?ticket=<?php echo $ticketNum; ?>"</>https://txgc.texas811.org/geocall/portal?ticket=<?php echo $ticketNum; ?></a></em></span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: You could try setting the src as like 'about:blank' and put a data element on it like `data-src="whatever"`, then on show, set the src to whatever `data('src')` is.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an `<iframe>` for this at all?  Bootstrap's Modal allows you to specify an outside source (ie. `<a href="http://..." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Foo</a>`...)

Comment: I am using iframe because your method gives me an error "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."